# How can I create a function that attaches multiple event handlers to multiple controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, .net-4.0

**Question:**
How can I create a function that attaches multiple event handlers to multiple controls?

**Intent:**
I am using C# to develop a windows forms application. I want to create a function that takes a collection of controls and a collection of event handlers. This function will attach the event handlers to the controls. What would be the most elegant, and reusable way to do this. I have a pretty ugly way to do this with delegates, but it is a but it is less work for me to just throw this into a loop, and abandoning the function.

**Behavior I basically want:**

```
foreach(Control control in controlCollection)
     foreach(EventHandler handler in eventHandlerCollection)
                    control.Event += handler;
```

**Function:**

`attachHandlers(? controlCollection, ? eventHandlers)`


**Edit:**
I am just going to subscribe all the handlers to the same event on all the controls. I didn't explicitly say that in my description, so I believe that is the reason for all of confusion.

Comment: How does your function know to which event (`Click`, `Enter`, `Validating`, ...) the handlers should be subscribed to?

Comment: Unclear what you are looking for: what kind of mapping you want from {controls,eventname} to a eventHandlers? There are multiple events on each control... It is also unclear if there is set of unique handlers per control or you want to use same handler for multiple (some?) controls.

Comment: You still haven't answered stakx's question.  How does the function know which event to subscribe the handler to.

Comment: @Servy The function I asked for was just a general use one where I would hardcode it. So that is how the function would know. Once again sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In a general use function you *wouldn't* hard code it, you'd want it to be, well, *general*.  In a specific instance, that's not generalized, you could hard-code it to a specific event.  Given that you plant to hard code it, what event do you plan to hard code it to?  Will it be an event in `Control`, will you need to restrict the types of input controls to some sub-type to ensure they all have the appropriate event, etc.

Comment: Then show me how keep from hardcoding it, this is a question. I honestly don't know how to get it more general, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the controls in question inherit from the same base class or interface (or they are the same class), you can do something like:

```
void AttachClickEventHandlers(List<IClickableControl> controls, List<MyClickHandler> eventHandlers)
{
    foreach (var control in controls)
        foreach (MyClickHandler handler in eventHandlers)
            control.Click += handler;
}
```

This assumes an interface like:

```
public interface IClickableControl
{
    event MyClickHandler Click;
}
```

Comment: Wow... I went to edit my question and came back and you basically wrote it.

Comment: How do you know you want to attach to the click event, or even the same event for each control in the collection?

Comment: @Servy I just assumed the OP wants to subscribe all the handlers to the same event on all the controls.

Comment: @dkroy please correct me or clarify your intention in the question.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I did my best to make the edits quick, but this question go answered so fast I didn't have time to clear up the confusion. I explicitly stated it above in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Servy clarified the method name.

Comment: You also don't need any interface if you're attaching the click event.  The click event exists in `Control` already, so you know all controls will have the event.  You also know that the delegate type will be `EventHandler`.  The code in the OP itself is actually not only sufficient, but superior.

Comment: @Servy if you can think of a better way to implement it now that I have most of the confusion cleared up I would love to see it. (Sorry if this sounds snarky, because that isn't my intention)

Comment: @dkroy I fail to see the problem in the code that you already posted.  What isn't working with it?