# Hovering over panel; change backcolor and forecolor

Tags: vb.net

I have a "menu bar" on the left side of my form. I am adding a panel(container for menu item), picturebox(icon) and label(menu text)

My ultimate goal is to make a mouse hover event which changes back color and forecolor of text every time a user hovers or leaves the menu item.

I understand how to achieve this:

```
Private Sub Panel6_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel6.MouseEnter
        Panel6.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Label3.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel6_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel6.MouseLeave
        Panel6.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(76, 76, 76)
        Label3.ForeColor = Color.White
    End Sub
```

This can be extremely unefficient based on how many menu items their are. My question is, how can I create a function(I believe thats what I'm looking for), so I can do this for every menu item without having to use the code for every control on every menu item.

Comment: Build a Custom Control or a UserControl that contains all the logic required to generate the effects you want. For simple things, like changing the color of the text, a custom control derived from Button could be enough (a Button can show a Bitmap and text, in different layouts, at the same time).

Comment: I have been researching the difference between custom control and user control and everything is explained in terms I really don't quite understand. Which would be better to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: A user control is specifically a class that inherits `UserControl`. You develop one in pretty much the same way you develop a form - add to project, build in designer with child controls and add code to handle events and perform actions - but then you use it like any other control. It's a good way to encapsulate the complex behaviour you want.

Comment: In this case, almost the same thing. A Custom Control, as a UserControl, can contain child controls, if needed. The UserControl has it's own designer, like a Form. A Custom Control doesn't. There's more to it, but for simple controls, it doesn't change much if you choose one or the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Panels with items acting like a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051560/panels-with-items-acting-like-a-button)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a function that attaches multiple event handlers to multiple controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953160/how-can-i-create-a-function-that-attaches-multiple-event-handlers-to-multiple-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using WinForms, you might do the following:

- Update your `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` handlers to not bind to a specific panel. You may also give them more generic names, like `Panel_MouseEnter` and `Panel_MouseLeave`.
- Create a private dictionary `PanelLabels`, in which put the corresponding label for each panel (in your form's load event handler).
- Update the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event handlers in such a way, that you use the sender parameter to determine the targeted panel and the PanelLabels dictionary to determine the targeted label.
- Call `AddHandler` in your form's load event handler to explicitly bind the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` event handlers to each of your panels.

Something like this:

```
Private ReadOnly PanelLabels As New Dictionary(Of Panel, Label)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PanelLabels.Add(Panel1, Label1)
    PanelLabels.Add(Panel2, Label2)
    PanelLabels.Add(Panel3, Label3)
    PanelLabels.Add(Panel4, Label4)
    PanelLabels.Add(Panel5, Label5)
    PanelLabels.Add(Panel6, Label6)

    For Each panel In PanelLabels.Keys
        AddHandler panel.MouseEnter, AddressOf Panel_MouseEnter
        AddHandler panel.MouseLeave, AddressOf Panel_MouseLeave
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Panel_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

    panel.BackColor = Color.LightGray
    PanelLabels(panel).ForeColor = Color.Black
End Sub

Private Sub Panel_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim panel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

    panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(76, 76, 76)
    PanelLabels(panel).ForeColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Hope this helps a little.

Edit:

I just saw that there might be some unwanted behavior as soon as you hover a label inside your panel. In that case, the panel's MouseLeave event gets triggered. Hmmm.

Edit 2:

You may also bind the events in a For-loop in the form's load event, using the registrations in PanelLabels. That will decrease the code's size even further. I have updated my code accordingly.